# Assigning ref to HTMLInputElement giving error in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-ref

In useRef variable cannot set to input element

```
   const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

   <Input name="answer" ref={inputRef}/>
```

On the `<Input ref="">` I'm Getting the following error

[image]

Any Idea How to Fix this. Thanks In Advance

My Full Code :

[image]

Comment: Is Input a class component or a functional component. If its a functional component are you using React.forwardRef?

Comment: Can you show us the full `Component` where it fails ? Thanks :)

Comment: If it is a class component, you'll still need to forward the ref, because otherwise the ref goes onto the class instance itself by default.

Comment: @Shubham Khatr I'm Using Functional Component

Comment: Full Code update. if possible to use "forwardRef" on this code -Shubham Khatri @Yooooomi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ref in not assigned to `HTMLInputElement` but an `Input` component. You need to define the type of it accordingly

Since Input is a functional component, you can't specify a ref on it directly, you need to forward the ref and for that you need to use `React.forwardRef`

```
const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
..
<Input name="answer" ref={inputRef}/>

...
const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref: React.Ref<HTMLInputeElement>) => (
  <input ref={ref} {...props} />
));
```

Since you are using semantic-ui-react, in order to pass on ref to the components, you need to make use of `Ref` component from the library

```
import {Ref } from 'semantic-ui-react';
...

const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
..
<Ref innerRef={inputRef}><Input name="answer" ref={inputRef}/></Ref>
```

Check a [`bit.dev`](https://bit.dev/semantic-org/semantic-ui-react/ref) for more details

Comment: I have updated full code. if possible can you tell i use React.forwardRef to fix this issue

Comment: Well we can't use forwardRef with an external library but I will update my post with possible solution

Comment: Wow thanks a lot @Shubham Khatri. I'm very beginner to react js so i really thanks to you for the support